# Why does Thor speak English?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-2011

In universe Thor and The Asgardians are the basis of Norse mythology.

So when we meet Thor and co why do they speak English, rather than a Norse/Nordic language?

This answer's ideally aimed at an in universe MCU answer, but if you have an alternative answer i'd love to hear it!

Comment: Thanks @valorum surprised that didn't appear appear on the list of duplicates when writing! Is it worth me deleting this ques?

Comment: @Paulie_D it appears you are correct!

Comment: We don't (as a matter of course) delete duplicates. They serve as google-bait to direct people to the other post; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7943/is-it-encouraged-to-delete-your-own-questions-if-they-have-possible-duplicates